# DEV C++ OpenGL and SOIL

Tags: c++

give me the solution for error :

```
[Linker error] undefined reference to `glGetString@4'
  more undefined references to `glGetString@4' follow
  [Linker error] undefined reference to `wglGetProcAddress@4'   
  [Linker error] undefined reference to `glTexImage2D@36'     
  [Linker error] undefined reference to `glDeleteTextures@8'    
  [Linker error] undefined reference to `glGenTextures@8'   
  [Linker error] undefined reference to `glGetIntegerv@8'   
  [Linker error] undefined reference to `glTexImage2D@36'  
  [Linker error] undefined reference to `glGenTextures@8'  
  [Linker error] undefined reference to `glTexImage2D@36'
```

I use DEV C++ and windows 7 64bit?

Comment: Also include your actual codee and explain your problem, edit your question...

Comment: Saying what is giving you have these errors would also be helpful. As in trying to use SOIL or something.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not linking against the gl library, so add it to your linker flags.

However, "give me the solution"???? Ever heard of please or asking politely?

Comment: Probably not a native English speaker

Comment: I assume so, but he managed to use this site, so his english should be good enough for some basic understanding. And asking politely is IMO something that is VERY basic when learning a new language.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the dynamic symbols.

Try adding to libraries:

OpenGl32.lib